# Is it possible to supply custom authentication mechanism to javaee security from within the webapp?

Tags: security, authentication, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8, application-server

I would like to use javaee security, but I need to authenticate users against an external proprietary authentication mechanism, which is different from LDAP and any other standard mechanisms coming with Wildfly. In particular, I would prefer if the authentication is taken care of by the application, not by the container. I only have come across [PolicyConfiguration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api//javax/security/jacc/PolicyConfiguration.html). But I think that it implies buiding an extension to be plugged into the underlying application server.

What I would like is to let application server obtain credentials in a standard javaee way, then execute a callback into the application in order to authorize them, and then establish current user together with his roles, so that I may use declarative security using annotations.

Is this possible in standard way? Or the only solution is to build an extension module for the application server?

Comment: [Yes](https://jaspic.zeef.com/arjan.tijms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An not so elegant solution would be to perform the login using [HttpServlet.login](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). You still need to configure a realm that would acknowledge the username and password you provide in the method call.

Another, more complex, solution would be to create an [JASPIC](https://jaspic-spec.java.net/) authentication provider. In short, you are in charge of the whole authentication process. Here is a collection of resources to get you started: [Zeef](https://jaspic.zeef.com/arjan.tijms)

Comment: Jaspic is close to what I was searching for. However, it seems that some configuration needs to be done to install my SAM into the application server. Isn't there a way to declare SAM as a class inside my WAR and register it from within the web app, e.g. in web.xml? I don't like the idea of amending configuration of AS. I would like just to deploy the app and make everything work.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Wildfly seems to be special in this case. I found this programmatic workaround, but its not pretty: http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2015/08/activating-jaspic-in-jboss-wildfly.html

Comment: Thanks for clarification. It is a pity, that this is not standardized, as Glassfish seems to automatically enable JASPIC, but Wildfly needs some adjustments.

Comment: "but Wildfly needs some adjustments" - that is very unfortunate, otherwise WildFly works really well. Someone should create an issue for this or ask them about it.